# Converting Date to const char*

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I made a `Date` class and I am trying to create a conversion method so you can cast a `Date` object to a `const char*` "string". It has to be `const char*`, **not** `string`.

However, I am finding some issues I cannot resolve.

This is my method:

```
Date::operator char*() const {
    tm date = { 0, 0, 0, day_, month_ - 1, year_ - 1900, 0, 0, -1 };
    mktime(&date);

    char* weekday[] = { "sunday", ..., "saturday" };
    char* month[] = { "january", ..., "diciembre" };

    char string[50];
    sprintf(string, "%s %d / %s / %d", weekday[fch.tm_wday], day_, month[fch.tm_mon], year_);

    return string;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
warning: address of local variable ‘cadena’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  char string[50];
```

If I add the `static` tag for the string variable, it will be shared, and I don't want that.

How could I do this?

Comment: You have tagged your question 'c++', not 'c'. Is there any special reason why you don't want to use `std::string`?

Comment: Yes, it has to bee const char*, not string.

Comment: You must realize that `char const*` is _not_ a string type. It is a mere pointer. You can do things with pointers - but you need to define a contract for memory management. One approach might be to allocate dynamic memory and return the buffer to the caller; the caller would then be responsible for deleting it. Other approach is to make the caller provide a buffer for you to fill.

Comment: You could maybe move `char string[50]` out of your method and make it a private member of the class instead... but it's contents could still change if you modify the date for that instance.  Why can't you return `std::string` and get the `const char *` from it afterward?

Comment: I tried to do that. I tried to create a `char* string` attribute and then dynamically reserve memory when the method were called, but I got an error. So I declared a local variable in the method and there I would dynamically allocate it. Now it works. It is driving me crazy that everyone is mentioning `string`. I cannot use it!!! I was asked not to. I know life would be marvelous just with `string`.

Comment: How about a method that writes to a passed-in buffer and returns a pointer to it?  Then use the method call instead of the cast.

Answer (score 2):

Define your buffer at class level, and return it from your method after writing in it.

But keep in mind that it's a stupid way to work because (1) subsequent calls to the method will alter the buffer, affecting the previous callers if they still keep that pointer, and (2) because it violates the Single Responsibility Principle - the particulars of the last formatting operation logically do not belong at all to the state of the date class. Also, the buffer must be marked as `mutable` to be modified from your `const` method, which is a clear sign that you are violating what are the expected responsibilities of your class.

In alternative, the "classic C" method would be to change the method to receive a buffer from the caller (along with its size), and just write in it. This shifts the burden of memory management on the caller (where it logically belongs), but makes the syntax to use the method quite a bit heavier.

Both these methods are clumsy and/or suboptimal in functionality; I won't even mention the possibility of returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, since it has the same overhead of an `std::string` but without the automatic memory management (so it's definitely the most idiotic choice).

As already said elsewhere, the correct C++ way is to return an `std::string`, which handles by itself the lifetime of the allocated memory. Unless you are in extremely peculiar conditions, there's no excuse not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You created a variable named `string` inside of the function, which will get out of scope (i.e. become invalid to reference) once the function returns. You also returned a pointer to it, which means you're referencing a region of memory that is no longer valid.

Consider returning an `std::string` instead, which does automatic memory management for you.

**EDIT:** If that doesn't do it, you can always have a `static` array and return a pointer to it.

```
Date::operator const char*() const
{
    static char str[50];
    // fill in array
    return str;
}
```

Of course, you cannot do the following now:

```
Date d1{...};
Date d2{...};

const char* d1_str = s1;
const char* d2_str = s2;
```

because the array used to convert the date into a string is shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: I DO NOT want to use `string`, I knew someone would say this. I want to create a conversion method to `const char*`.

Comment: It's obvious that someone would have said that, because using a C++ string (or similar stuff) is the most sane alternative. In all the other cases you have either to have a buffer local to your class (which means that previously returned values will change content at every new call) or return memory allocated with new, which has the same overhead of std::string without its niceties (in particular, the automatic lifetime management).

Comment: I said that I didn't want to use the static tag since it will be shared.

Comment: @dabadaba What remains then is to dynamically allocate memory and return a pointer to it, hoping the user will call `delete`. Not the cleanest thing to do, though.

Comment: I think that would be it. However, if I declare a `string_aux` attribute with the type `char*`, if I try to dynamically allocate memory to it, like `string_aux = new char[50]` in the `operator char*() const` method I can't do it.

Comment: @dabadaba Well, the conversion operator is `const`, so you'd have to make `string_aux` **`mutable`**. This keeps getting worse and worse. Make yourself a favor: return `std::string`.